# How to calculate column with multiple table in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have two table :

```
description
id | receipt | price | quantity |
1  | 0001    | 50    | 1        |
2  | 0001    | 20    | 1        |
3  | 0002    | 30    | 1        |
4  | 0003    | 60    | 1        |
5  | 0004    | 50    | 1        |
6  | 0005    | 100   | 1        |

statement
id | receipt | datetime   | group_id | account_id | deposit | status |
1  | 0001    | 2019-09-02 | 1        | 1          | 2       | credit |
2  | 0002    | 2019-09-01 | 1        | 1          | 5       | debit  |
3  | 0003    | 2018-08-01 | 1        | 1          | 3       | credit |
4  | 0004    | 2018-08-30 | 1        | 1          | 5       | debit  |
5  | 0005    | 2019-09-03 | 1        | 1          | 10      | credit |
```

This is my calculation :

```
total = [credit(price * quantity) - credit(deposit)] - [debit(price * quantity) - debit(deposit)]
```

how can i subtract credit(price * quantity) with deposit ('SELECT SUM(deposit) WHERE status = 'credit' GROUP BY YEAR(datetime)') This is my query :

```
SELECT
  YEAR(`statement`.`datetime`) AS `year`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN `statement`.`status` = 'credit' THEN (`description`.`price` * `description`.`quantity`) ELSE 0 END)-
  (--SELECT deposit FROM statement WHERE status = 'credit' GROUP BY YEAR(datetime)--) //something like this
  -
  SUM(CASE WHEN `statement`.`status` = 'debit' THEN (`description`.`price` * `description`.`quantity`) ELSE 0 END)-
  (--SELECT deposit FROM statement WHERE status = 'debit' GROUP BY YEAR(datetime)--) //something like this
FROM `statement` JOIN `description`
  ON `statement`.`receipt` = `description`.`receipt`
WHERE
  `statement`.`group_id` = '1' AND
  `statement`.`account_id` = '1'
GROUP BY YEAR(`statement`.`datetime`)
```

this is result should be :

```
year  | credit_price | credit_deposit | debit_price | debit_deposit | total |
2019  | 170.0        | 12.0           | 30.0        | 5.0           | 133.0 |
2018  | 60.0         | 3.0            | 50.0        | 5.0           | 12.0  |
```

Comment: Question is missing expected results which makes it more easy for us to verify our written query? See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a `MAX` (or `MIN` / `ANY_VALUE`) with `CASE WHEN` for the `deposit` too. You don't need a additional sub-query.

```
SELECT YEAR(s.`datetime`) AS `year`,
  (
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.`status` = 'credit' THEN d.`price` * d.`quantity` ELSE 0 END) -
    MAX(t_deposit.`credit`)
  ) -
  (
    SUM(CASE WHEN s.`status` = 'debit' THEN d.`price` * d.`quantity` ELSE 0 END) -
    MAX(t_deposit.`debit`)
  ) AS total
FROM `statement` s INNER JOIN `description` d ON s.`receipt` = d.`receipt`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT YEAR(`statement`.`datetime`) AS year,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `statement`.`status` = 'debit' THEN deposit ELSE 0 END) AS debit,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `statement`.`status` = 'credit' THEN deposit ELSE 0 END) AS credit
  FROM `statement`
  GROUP BY YEAR(`statement`.`datetime`)
) t_deposit ON YEAR(s.`datetime`) = t_deposit.`year`
WHERE s.`group_id` = '1' 
  AND s.`account_id` = '1'
GROUP BY YEAR(s.`datetime`)
ORDER BY YEAR(s.`datetime`) DESC
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92a04ef3b91ff893b9f886da27d9906b)

Comment: The minus bit seems a little long-winded , but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already try SUM(CASE WHEN s.`status` = 'credit' THEN s.`deposit` ELSE 0 END) in year 2019, and the result showing '4'. It should be '2' because one row in (receipt no 0001) in statement table is representing two row (receipt no 0001) in description table.

Comment: @AffandyKhaleed what are the expected results for 2018 and 2019? Also checkout the updated answer.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch the query script you gave me is correct but using MAX() for 'deposit' column get a problems if i add new data. Please checkout my update table and result question above. I appreciate your help, Thank you.

Comment: @AffandyKhaleed - see the update (added a left join with sums per year).

Comment: @SebastianBrosch Yes! thank you so much sir.. i really appreciate it.. my problems solve. :)